# Compute $\oint_{|z|=r}z^2 \sin(\bar z)dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

As mentioned above I am interested in the value of $$\oint_{|z|=r}z^2 \sin(\bar z)dz$$ where $r>0$ although I'm somewhat helpless at the moment. What I got so far: $$z^2 \sin(\bar z)=z^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(\bar z)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=|z|^2\overline{\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n-1}}{(2n+1)!}}$$ and therefore we can write the integral as $$\overline{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\oint_{|z|=r}|z|^2(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n-1}}{(2n+1)!}dz}$$ but this seems to just make matters worse. Any good approach to this?

Comment: Why did $z^{2}$ become $|z|^{2}$?

Comment: I pulled out $\bar{z}^2$ from the $\sin$.

Comment: $$\sin(\bar{z}) = \sin\left(\frac{r^2}{z}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for this tip! So I can say $z^2\sin(\bar z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(r^2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}z^{-2n+1}$ and use the residue theorem? The residue should at $0$ should be $-r^6/6$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The identity is valid on the circle, and because you now have a contour  integral of an analytic function (apart from the essential singularity at the origin), you can apply the residue theorem.

Comment: @RedLantern The mistake in your original approach was assuming $\oint \overline{f(z)}dz = \overline{\oint f(z)dz}$; this identity is false.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z\bar z=r^2$ we have $$\oint_{|z|=r}z^2 \sin(\bar z)dz=\oint_{|z|=r}z^2 \sin(\frac{r^2}{z})dz$$
now youse $$z^2 \sin(\frac{r^2}{z})=z^2(\frac{r^2}{z}-\frac{r^6}{3!z^3}+\frac{r^{10}}{5!z^5}-\ldots)$$ we get that

> $$\oint_{|z|=r}z^2 \sin(\bar z)dz=-2{\pi}i(\frac{r^6}{3!})$$

Comment: I think there is an error with your $r^2$. The powers of $r^2$ should also increase.

Comment: @Dear RedLantern, thanks your comment